# How to wait a given time to run an action-SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to know how to run an action after making the console count a given time. For example printing 'hello' after 3 seconds.
Thank you!!

Comment: What have you considered and tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `NSTimer` class.

Example usage:

```
var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(3, target: self, selector: Selector("sayHello"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

Somewhere else in your class...

```
func sayHello() {
    println("Hello")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create delays with following ways!!
You can create a delay using `asynAfter`

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + <secondsToDelay>) {
   // Put your code here that you want to execute after delay
}
```

Another way is calling a function itself after a delay using objc's `perform selector`

```
perform(#selector(delayedMethod), with: nil, afterDelay: <secondsToDelay>)

@objc func delayedMethod() {
    print("My delayed method call")
}
```

Of course you can also use `Timer` like in Woodstock's answer.